# Fail dbt run based on Query Result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am trying to run a procedure using Custom Macro. The Macro run the SQL(Call Statememnt) present in the Model sql file.

I am able to run the procedure but my objective is to capture the response of the procedure and fail the dbt run if response is 'Failure'. The procedure can return string 'Success' or 'Failure'.
I am able to capture the return but not sure how to explicitly fail the run based on the return value.

Macro:

```
{% materialization call_proc, adapter='snowflake' -%}

{% set query %}
use schema "{{ database }}"."{{ schema }}"
{% endset %}

{% do run_query(query) %}

{%- call statement('main',fetch_result=True) -%}
{{ sql }}
{%- endcall -%}  

{% if execute %}
{%- set QRY_RSLT = load_result('main')['data'][0][0] -%}
{{log (QRY_RSLT)}}
{% endif %}

{{ return({'relations': []}) }}

{%- endmaterialization %}
```

Model SQL:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='call_proc',
    database='TEST_DB',
    schema = 'TEST'
    )
}}

call  "{{ database }}"."{{ schema }}".TEST_PROC('TEST');
```

Checking the QRY_RSLT in logs I can see Success/Failure being printed. How to fail the model if 'Failure' is returned by Proc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my other answer, I don't think it's a good idea to use a custom materialization to call a stored procedure. You're better off using a macro for this.

But putting that aside, you can raise an exception using jinja:

```sql
{% if execute %}
{%- set QRY_RSLT = load_result('main')['data'][0][0] -%}
{% if QRY_RSLT == "failure" %}
    {{ exceptions.raise_compiler_error("Invalid `QRY_RESULT`. Got: " ~ QRY_RSLT) }}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @tconbeer. If I use a macro, then i will have to place the CALL statement in the macro body. Let's suppose i have 10 procedures to call then i will need to create 10 macro's? Isn't it? Or i can call a generic macro which need not be a materialization using model sql?

Comment: you could have one macro that contains 10 sql statements, separated by `;`. Or you could have 10 macros that each contain one sql statement, and use another macro to call all 10 macros. Note that in a macro, you need to actually call `run_query` or the sql won't be executed. Here are the docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/hooks-operations#about-operations

Comment: but that is the point if i create a materialization. I can have 10 model sql file calling the materialization and passing the CALL statement. I know it is same as creating 10 macros but those macros will have duplicated code also. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't see why a normal macro would lead to more code duplication. Models are really supposed to map to database relations (tables, views).

Comment: @tconbeer does this really works? I've tested it and in case the query in the `call statement` fails - the dbt model fails. Any ideas?

Comment: the point of this is to raise an exception when the query returns specific data; you unfortunately can't catch an exception raised by the database if the query raises one